# ActionScript bit operations encoding audio to a FLV

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bit-manipulation, flv

I'm creating an FLV via AS3 using BitmapData; the resulting flv has no audio. So I'm trying to add an audio track on top. I've converted a Sound object's bytearray into a WAV bytearray.

I'm adding on FLV headers (specifically audio headers). I'm looking through documentation ([pdf here](http://ospace.tistory.com/attachment/jk12.pdf)), and this is how it specifies how to write the header:

[image]

I'm pretty new to bytes/bits and bitwise operators, so looking at how the video header was created, I'm wondering about a few things:

When it says bit flags, does this mean that all 4 options should be combined into a bitmask? Is that what the "0x08 : AUDIO" is telling me? That it should be in a byte (base-8, right?). So to store these options, would I do something like this?

> //Write byte with options: uncompressed, 44khz, 16-bit, stereo
>
> var tag:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
>
> tag.writeByte(0x0321);

This seems wrong, ugh.

Or can I use tag.writeByte(2) to add each option on one at a time? I've also seen tag.writeByte(2 >>> 0xff) and what-not. I'm thoroughly confused. Could anyone help, or suggest a book or write-up where I might be able to figure this out?

[image]

In this image when it says UB(4), UB(2), UB(1), UB(1) under type for each field, does the "UB" tell me that they should all be combined? What does the [#] mean in this situation?

I've got my work cut out for me; but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source lib to encode Flv at runtime in as3, did you tried : https://github.com/zeropointnine/leelib/tree/master/src/leelib/util/flvEncoder ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I swear I looked all around the internet for this with no luck, how did you find this? Or is there a repository for code libraries like this?

Comment: I found this by google for a personnal project but if you are looking for a good lib list go there : http://www.adrianparr.com/?p=83, it is the best web page ever for flash libs (this web site is cool too : http://www.as3gamegears.com/tag/mit/)